# Is faster to read text file or add elements to ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files

I currently add elements to ArrayList using submethod and then call it in the main function:

```
public void addProductAll(){
        productCode.add("202LED");
        productCode.add("202WLED");
        productCode.add("WWR"); 
        productCode.add("CUBLED");
```

The problem is that I will have 200 different product codes. 
So my question is what is the fastest way to add elements to the ArrayList? Like I am doing now or maybe read them from text document? Is there a better approach to this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this yourself. Just do:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// Add manually
System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
```

and

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
// Read from file
System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.nanoTime() - start));
```

Comment: "Just do" but also just read [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/3788176)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely an I/O operation would be slower. You need to provide a few more details, for example how often do those codes change? I doubt you mean to add them manually directly into the code.